# Is it possible to make an automation tool that could see indepth details about a .net program?

Tags: .net, automation

Recently I've been using TestComplete for my automation scripts and it works great. After seeing that it was able to see indepth information about the .net application (such as button names and attributes and etc) I was curious if this feat would be possible to make normally.

Is it possible to create a tool that displays information to such an extent that TestComplete does? More as a side project for me to create an automation tool.

(Side note: the only application I deal with are usually .NET sometimes with Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you need is **Reflection** Class.

**Manual**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

**Implementation**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET

Comment: Thanks! Because it's in the .NET framework, does this mean I would be able to code this in C#? I've used VB for a lot of .net projects, but I keep hearing C# is pretty good.

Comment: Hi, yea C#.net is better. However, there are certain sites that let you convert VB code to C#.

Comment: Alright. I'm just looking to create an application to be able to see some of the in depth names of buttons and etc on the GUI of my application. To pretty create an automation program.

Comment: That's great and interesting. Reflections would be the best choice.